# Cant add a Jquery plugin inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, plugins

Hi I have a JQuery plugin that takes an array of Orders and creates rows for each Order in the array. No issues here. However if one of these Orders meets a condition it should add a textbox in one of the TD cells.  When I debug I can see it adding the textBox but when the next row is created which requires a textBox the previous textbox gets removed. i have this inside a close so not sure what to do. So the result is I only get textboxes in the last row.

If I add the textBox as html it works fine but I want it as a plugin as I need to bind several events KeyUp/Down MouseWheel, Click. etc
The textbox plugin control (gep_inputcontrol) just creates the html and binds events, nothing fancy.

Any help appreciated.

---

```
var _table = $('#orderTable', this);
for (var i = 0; i < params.orders.length; i++) {
    var row = createRow(params.orders[i]);
    _table.append(row);
}
```

---

```
function createRow(order){
    var unmatchedStake = (order.requestedStake - order.matchedStake);
    var partMatched = (unmatchedStake > 0);


    var tr = $(String.format('<tr id="order_{0}" class="{1}"/>' ,order.orderId, ((i % 2) == 0) ? 'gep-altrow' : 'gep-row'));

            tr.append(String.format('<td class="gep-icon gep-status">{0}</td>', order.orderStatusId));
            tr.append(String.format('<td class="gep-selectionname">{0} {1} {2}</td>', GBEUtils.getEventName(order.eventClassifierFullName()), gep._settings.resources.general.polarity[order.polarityId], order.selectionName()));
            tr.append(String.format('<td class="gep-odds betSlipRowPrice">{0}</td>', order.averageMatchedPrice));
            tr.append(String.format('<td class="gep-unmatched betSlipRowStake">{0}</td>', com.base.formatDecimal(order.requestedStake - order.matchedStake,2)));
            tr.append(String.format('<td class="gep-matched">{0}</td>', com.base.formatDecimal(order.matchedStake,2)));
            tr.append(String.format('<td class="gep-action"><span  class="gep-icon"/></td>', order.orderStatusId));


             //var tablerow = $(String.format('#order_{0}',order.orderId), _table);
            //(function (_table, tr, i, unmatchedStake, tablerow) {
            if(unmatchedStake > 0)//part matched
            {

                $('.gep-unmatched', tr).gep_inputcontrol({
                    type:'STAKE', 
                    ccSymbol:clientObject.state.ccSymbol,
                    value: unmatchedStake,  
                    decimalValue:unmatchedStake,
                    onMouseWheeled: function(e, ev){
                        gep.inputControlWheeled(e, ev);
                        gep.calculateRowProfit(e, false);
                        return false;
                        },
                    onArrowClicked: function(e){
                        gep.onArrowClick(e);
                        return false;
                        }
                    });

                    //$('.gep-unmatched', tr).html($('.gep-unmatched', tr).html());


                $('.gep-odds', tr).gep_inputcontrol({
                    type:'PRICE', 
                    value:order.requestedPrice, 
                    decimalValue:order.requestedPrice,
                    onMouseWheeled: function(e, ev){
                        gep.inputControlWheeled(e, ev);
                        gep.calculateRowProfit(e, false);
                        return false;
                    },
                    onArrowClicked: function(e){
                        gep.onArrowClick(e);
                        return false;
                    }
                    });

                $('.gep-action .gep-icon', tr).addClass("gep-icon-delete");

                $('.gep-icon-delete', tr).bind("click", function(){
                    alert("delete");
                    toggleCurrentBetSlipBet(this);
                    return false;
                });

            }


            // })(_table, tr, i, unmatchedStake, tablerow);

            return tr;
```

}

The textbox plugin creates a table with input box and two anchor tags.

```
/********************
GEP.gep_inputcontrol // stake input, price input box
********************/
(function ($) {

var _templatePrice = $('<table class="gep-inputcontrol" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td rowspan="2"><input type="text" size="5" class="gep-inputcontrol-price" /></td><td><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);" class="gep-inputup"></a></td></tr><tr><td> <a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);" class="gep-inputdown"></a> </td></tr></table>');
var _templateStake = $('<table class="gep-inputcontrol" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td rowspan="2"><span class="gep-ccsymbol" /> <input type="text" size="5" class="gep-inputcontrol-stake" /> </td> <td> <a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);" class="gep-inputup"></a></td></tr><tr><td> <a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);" class="gep-inputdown"></a> </td></tr> </table>');
var _template;


var _settings = null;
var _instance;
var methods = {
    init: function (options) {
        _settings = options;
        //options.type = 'STAKE'or 'PRICE'

        _template = (options.type == 'STAKE')? _templateStake: _templatePrice;

        $('.gep-ccsymbol',_template).html(options.ccSymbol);




        this.html(_template);
        $('input', this).attr('value', options.value);
        $('input', this).attr('initialvalue', options.decimalValue);
        $('input', this).attr('decimalValue', options.decimalValue);


        $('input', this).bind("mousewheel", function (ev) {
            _settings.onMouseWheeled.call(null, this, ev.originalEvent);
        });      

        $('.gep-inputup', this).bind("click", function (e) {
            _settings.onArrowClicked.call(null, this);
        });            
        $('.gep-inputdown', this).bind("click", function (e) {
            _settings.onArrowClicked.call(null, this);
        });


        _instance = this;
        return this;

    },
    show: function (params) {
        alert("show" + params);
    },
    hide: function () {
        // GOOD
    },
    update: function (content) {
        // !!! 
    }
};

$.fn.gep_inputcontrol = function (method) {

    // Method calling logic
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.gep_inputcontrol');
    }

};

})(jQuery);
```

To elaborate a bit more, I did some small unit tests

This works..

```
$('.gep-odds', clientObject.liveBetsPane).gep_inputcontrol({
        type: 'PRICE',
        value: 5,
        decimalValue: 5,
        onMouseWheeled: function (e, ev) {
            gep.inputControlWheeled(e, ev);
            gep.calculateRowProfit(e, false);
            return false;
        },
        onArrowClicked: function (e) {
            gep.onArrowClick(e);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This does NOT work...(Only puts TEXT box in last row) But I need to do it this way as I need values of each row.

```
$('.gep-odds', clientObject.liveBetsPane).each(function () {
    $(this).gep_inputcontrol({
        type: 'PRICE',
        value: 5,
        decimalValue: 5,
        onMouseWheeled: function (e, ev) {
            gep.inputControlWheeled(e, ev);
            gep.calculateRowProfit(e, false);
            return false;
        },
        onArrowClicked: function (e) {
            gep.onArrowClick(e);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the code that creates the html for the textbox. Can we see this code please. I believe it is the source of the problem.

Comment: Hi LydOn thanks for getting on this. I have edited the post, now it contains the plugin for texbox (gep_inputcontrol)

Comment: Does this mean it can't be answered, should I provide more information, how long do I leave it up here before deleting if no answer.

Comment: Have been busy at work so haven't had time to look at your question. One thing I thought it might be is a unique ID for the textbox. In the code where the textbox is created, try giving it a unique ID. I'll have a look at it later today hopefully.

Comment: Ya I though the same thing and tried that but didnt work, I've tried closures in different areas and put ids on both the TD and the TR which brought me to the unit tests at the bottom. If I can explain why my plugin does not work inside an $.each I might be closer to solution. I will have to test does this happen all plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I removed dollar from the template and it worked fine.

```
var _templatePrice = $('<table cla...
```

is now 
    var _templatePrice = '<table cla...

Although it sets the html for the last row it was moving for the other rows.

Thanks to me.... :)